# Are gasless functions that can be performed client-side possible in solidity?

Tags: solidity, gas, evm

Suppose I have a contract which performs an arbitrary mathematical calculation like:

```
contract Add2Plus2 
{
    ...
     
    function add2plus2() external view 
    {
        return 2 + 2;
    }

    ...

}
```

The function does not rely on any state information of the contract, and does not actually require any knowledge of what is happening on the Ethereum chain, the EVM or otherwise. It just performs a basic mathematical calculation.

I am aware that [view functions](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/solidity/solidity_view_functions.htm) do not modify stateful variables within a contract. However, they cost gas to perform.

**Question:**

Is there a way to define such a function that is performed client-side, without any interaction with the EVM - and hence be gasless? If so, how would such a function be defined?

Answer (score 1):

`View` and `Pure` functions are gasless only if they do not get called from the contract internally.

The function in the question would be gasless if called externally. `Pure` functions **do not read or modify** state, where as `View` functions **read but do not modify state**.